# Babel error: Invalid Version: 70001900000

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader, babel-preset-env, babel-core, browserslist

> Disclaimer: I haven't found anything useful in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

I recently upgraded the following Babel dependencies:

```
@babel/core          ^7.15.0  ->  7.21.5
@babel/preset-env    ^7.14.7  ->  7.21.5
@babel/preset-react  ^7.14.5  ->  7.18.6
```

and jest doesn't work anymore. My tests are TSX files and I use preset `ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel-esm`:

```
FAIL  spec/javascripts/ActiveDocs/components/FormAlert.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: /opt/app-root/src/project/spec/javascripts/__mocks__/global-mocks.js: Invalid Version: 70001900000

      at new SemVer (node_modules/semver/semver.js:314:11)
      at compare (node_modules/semver/semver.js:647:10)
      at Function.lt (node_modules/semver/semver.js:688:10)
      at PluginPass.pre (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex/node_modules/@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin/lib/index.js:50:44)
          at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
          at run.next (<anonymous>)
          at transform.next (<anonymous>)
      at evaluateSync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
      at sync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:542:31)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:671:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:723:19)
```

EDIT:
It's not a problem with jest but with Babel. The same error happens when running webpack for transpilation.

Here's a link to the repository with these changes: https://github.com/3scale/porta/pull/3340/files

EDIT 2:

This is what the error looks like during compilation

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/active_docs.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: /opt/system/app/javascript/packs/active_docs.ts: Invalid Version: 70001900000
    at new SemVer (/opt/system/node_modules/semver/semver.js:314:11)
    at compare (/opt/system/node_modules/semver/semver.js:647:10)
    at Function.lt (/opt/system/node_modules/semver/semver.js:688:10)
    at PluginPass.pre (/opt/system/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex/node_modules/@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin/lib/index.js:50:44)
    at transformFile (/opt/system/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:73:27)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/opt/system/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:24:12)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/opt/system/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:22:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
    at /opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
    at /opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:189:28
    at /opt/system/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:68:7
    at /opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:113:33
    at step (/opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:287:14)
    at /opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/opt/system/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was reported in https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15604 and fixed in https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/15605. The fix is included in the version v7.21.8 (see [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)), specifically, the package `@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin` needs to be upgraded to v7.21.8 (might not upgrade on its own if it's a sub-dependency)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was missing the target browsers. The error disappears when I set an array of supported browsers in my package.json:

```
"browserslist": [
  "chrome >= 107",
  "firefox >= 105",
  "edge >= 107"
],
```

I assume adding a `.browserslistrc` or equivalent config file will also work.